# Multi-Tenant Database Schema Creation

Tags: sql-server

I need to create a Multi-tenant schema.
I have searched a lot, but I haven't got any concrete solution to create one.
Any example would be highly appreciated.

I'm using SQL-SERVER 2008.

I need to use same **database for multiple clients**, but I need a secure way to implement it.
I have the following scenario:

I have 10 tenants, each will be having a separate TenantID.
I need to provide custom UI to each user based on the TenantID of the user currently logged in.
Forex: Logo, Css files all will be based on the TenantID.
Can I achieve it?
If yes, how?
If no, then what is the alternative?

Please help.

Comment: Your question seems overly broad. Also you need to explain exactly what you mean by "I need a secure way to implement it." What ***specific*** issues do you need to overcome?

Comment: I closed this as NARQ since you are basically providing no info and asking for a novella on database design.  If you would like to add **specific** details you need assistance with, and some examples of the kinds of data you will be storing, please edit the question and flag it for moderator attention to be reopened and we can reopen it for you.

Comment: @JNK
I have edited the question and flagged it.
Thanks

Comment: @RajWadhwa Most of the info in your edit is non-database related.  Why do you need a single database instead of one per client?  What data will be in the db?

Comment: @JNK
That is the requirement of the application.
Data like Profile of the employees of different companies, their salary details, their transaction details etc.
I just need a way by which I can implement this in database. That is the problem.
Thanks

Comment: You're still not describing a database problem, you're describing either an application design problem or some other issue.  The DB problem would be related to "How do I store the data XYZ and keep it separate based on ABC?"  You still haven't explained why you need all your clients in the same DB.  Do they share data?

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest Microsoft Dynamics CRM DB model.
it has one meta-database ,contains all other db references and which client matches which db. you can find db models on http://www.mibuso.com/downloads.asp?category=crm

Crm creates one db for organization and put the info of the new created db and which clients can use this db/organization into meta-database.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I need to implement it myself. Any other alternative at the database level.

Comment: well, you can download and try the dynamics crm and investigate whole DB on your server.http://www.microsoft.com/tr-tr/download/details.aspx?id=27822  or here is another example of different approach http://shard.codeplex.com/